# Use Microsoft Graph to list out tenants

Tags: powershell, charts, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a powershell-script using Microsoft Graph to automate tasks for Microsoft 356 Admin senter for our tenants.

I would like the option to list out all tenants that we have, so I dont have to log in to the CSP-admin we use for each tenant. Basically what I want is to log on to my account, and list out all tenants that we manage.

The purpose of this is to create a script where I can list tenants, and select that tenant I want to add and remove users, manage emails through the ExchangeOnline-module etc.

Any ideas?

I tried to google and ask copilot etc, I did not find a lot of documentation on this in the MgGraph-documentation site. I tried searching through the get-command "*graph*" and "*tenant*" but I did not find anything usable.

Comment: Did you assign roles?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/permissions-overview